# Any ideas for realizing this "feature"?

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'm currently developing an iOS app for my company and I'm really new to app development. I have a styling guideline from our companys' art agency.

[Here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHGVt.png) of what I'm trying to accomplish.

As you can see on the pictures' bottom there a some "stacked" / "overlapped" panels (where the arrow is pointing at) The first one should have a title and content - the other two just an title. There should be no functionality (just by touching on them as a whole, to navigate to the detail view) - but I have no clue for realizing this.

I had a look at `UIStackView` but im not sure if this is the right control for doing this.

Is there a control for doing this, or do i have to place those views manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you truly don't need any other functionality other than tapping on them you're going to have to layout three UIViews yourself like you see in the picture.

It looks like the top one is a UIView with room for a title Label, a time label (maybe?), and a detail Label. So start with a UIView, create your labels, and add them in one by one to the top view, taking care to set AutoLayout up correctly so the views are aligned like you see.

I would reccommend creating the back UIView first, then adding it, create the middle one, add it, then create the last one and add it. This way they will automatically be setup in the correct order "depth" wise

Edit: As you said your new, let met me add one more tip on how to implement this - I would put the layout of the three UIViews and text into a separate UIView subclass. Then, you can simply instantiate an instance of that UIView subclass and place it where you need in your layout like you would any other type of view or control.

Basically, by making your own subclasss, you create your own control that you were looking for originally.

Comment: thanks, i finally did this - calculating the frame of those views depending on my parents bounds!

Comment: I don't think you'll want to calculate frames manually. Since your new to iOS it may seem easier to do than to correctly implement constraints using autolayout, but it will make your app much more stable and able to adjust to a variety of screen sizes easily.